# bootstrap modals only working on some elements and not working on others.Elements are dynamically rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-modal

```
 <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

this is my html's head content.

my template contains Dynamically rendered post element(thumbnail) which contains a Modal.

```
 <li><div class="thumbnail" id="{{post.0.pk}}">
 <a href="#exampleModalLong{{post.0.pk}}" class="popup"  data-toggle="modal">(Input form)</a>
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong{{post.0.pk}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
```

........

javascript that renders these posts is:

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height()))
 {
 ready=false;
 $.ajax(
 {
 url:'/home/scroll/loadcontent/',
 method:'get',
 data:{posts:str},
 dataType:'json',
 success:function(response)
 {

 $("#col1").children('#tiles').append(response.col1);
 $("#col1").children('#tiles').append(response.col4);
 $("#col2").children('#tiles').append(response.col2);
 $("#col2").children('#tiles').append(response.col5);
 $("#col3").children('#tiles').append(response.col3);
 $("#col3").children('#tiles').append(response.col6);
 }
 }).always(function(){
            ready = true; //Reset the flag here
        });
 }
 }
 window.onscroll=yHandler;
```

in this arrangement all the elements that are rendered in col1($("#col1").children('#tiles').append(response.col1);) are having there modals working while any of the others is not...

Comment: $(window.location.hash).modal('show'); i have done this to manually invoke modal now on click is generating the hash location but it is not opening the modals in col2 and col3 yet.... same

Comment: $('#wrap').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="modal"]' ,function(event){
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
    });

Comment: Please fix your JavaScript indentation for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need.
Remove the *fade* class from the template

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())){
   ready=false;
   $.ajax({
      url: "/home/scroll/loadcontent/",
      method: "get",
      data: { 
          posts: str
     },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(response) {

         $("#col1").children('#tiles').append(response.col1);
         $("#col1").children('#tiles').append(response.col4);
         $("#col2").children('#tiles').append(response.col2);
         $("#col2").children('#tiles').append(response.col5);
         $("#col3").children('#tiles').append(response.col3);
         $("#col3").children('#tiles').append(response.col6);

       }
    })
    .always(function(){
        ready = true; //Reset the flag here
    });
 }

window.onscroll=yHandler
```

EDIT:

- In the template you're missing 2 closing tags for the last 2 divs.
- In the head you have included jQuery twice.
- Still I'm worried about *$("#col1")*, *$("#col2")* and *$("#col3")* having children with the same id *#tiles*
- I noticed some things...also...When the stuff like *{{post.0.pk}}* gets compiled?

Comment: that gives me a still and black screen .... maybe it is invoking all the modals in each rendered element at same time.

Comment: loading jquery twice was a problem...... and then i had to manually trigger the modal thank you...